# Lambda expressions with properties from base class

Tags: c#

I have several data classes and want to select an item from a list. We want to use a lambda expression to do so. But it seems not to work as expected when the select property is in the base class.
Base Class

```
public class BaseData 
{
   public bool isSelected;
   public int distance;
}
```

Derived class

```
public class PlayerData: BaseData 
{
   public string nickname
}
```

Some Logic

```
public class SelectData 
{
   public PlayerData GetPlayer()
   {
       List<PlayerData> playerdata = new List<PlayerData>();
       // this list gets its data from a JSON file and is populated as expected.
       // now we want to select the player data for processing.

       PlayerData player = playerdata.Find(x => x.isSelected);

       // on this part we unexpected results, when i move the isSelected to the class PlayerData it works perfect but than it is not possible to write a generic extensions with these Data classes.
      return player;
  }
}
```

We want to use a extension something like

```
public static int AddToDropDown<T>(this Dropdown dropdown,
                                       List<T> baseDataList,
                                       string displayText,
                                       string iconName,
                                       bool isSelected) where T : new() {
enter code here --- add to dropdown and add the item to PlayerData or ...
}
```

There are no complier errors... what is wrong?

Comment: what does this `Public class SelectData() {` mean ?

Comment: Just a class i use with some buttons to add information, i made a typo ... it should be "public void  SelectData"

Comment: Can you give us more samples of what is a possible input and also the declaration of `Public class SelectData` shouldn't compile, please publish the entire relevant class and usage, for more details.

Comment: The above example was just small.  I will select the complete parts i use. and post it

Comment: Not sure why the derived class inheriting from another concrete class when it just has one string property. You should be using class composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works fine:
See this example here, probably there is something else causing the issue:

```
public void Main()
{
  List<PlayerData> playerdata = new List<PlayerData>
  {
    new PlayerData
    {
       isSelected = true,
       distance = 3,
       nickname = "First",

    },
    new PlayerData
    {
        isSelected = true,
        distance = 3,
         nickname = "Second",
    },
    new PlayerData
    {
       isSelected = true,
       distance = 3,
       nickname = "Third",
    }
  };

  PlayerData player = playerdata.Find(x => x.isSelected);
  Console.WriteLine(player);

}
public class BaseData 
{
   public bool isSelected;
   public int distance;
}
public class PlayerData: BaseData 
{
   public string nickname;
   public override string ToString() { return this.nickname;}
}
```

The result is 'First' as expected since it is the first player in the list.

Comment: Yes i see, but my line--             Club selectedClub = clubs.Find(x => x.DisplayName == homeClubDropDown.options[index].text && x.Home); still would not work.

Comment: are you quite sure the data meets the criteria of the expression ? have you used debugging to see the data in the list because I think your data do not meet the expression`s criteria

Comment: You are correct i have a mismatch withy JSON data... stupid mistake. thanks

Comment: If you fixed it and the answer helped you please consider marking this as correct answer so other users do not see it as unresolved